# Ruby StringScanner used for lexing : how to get the line number?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am using StringScanner for lexical analysis like this :

```
def next
 @scanner.skip(/\s+/)
 value,kind=nil,nil
 TOKEN_DEF.each{|tok,regex| (kind=tok;break) if @scanner.scan(regex)}
 return Token.new(kind,value,@line,@scanner.pos)
end
```

At first approximation, this works well, except that I can't figure out how to now get the @line number.

I have read the doc, where begin_of_line? method seems appropriate, but I cannot figure how to use it.

Comment: What kind of information in @scanner.pos?

Comment: position from start...should be from begin of line for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the text that you are scanning in a variable and use 'count'

I use the following in my code:

```
def current_line_number; @text[0..@scanner.pos].count("\n") + 1; end
```

Comment: Note that `pos` gives a byte count, but `@text[…]` expects a character count, so this code won't work if there are multibyte chars. Instead, use `@text[0..@scanner.charpos]` or `@text.byteslice(0, @scanner.pos)`. (The latter may be faster.)

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't seem ready to go and for sure somewhere else more elegant solution, it just should give you something to think about.

```
class Retry < StandardError
end

class TextScanner
  def initialize(filename)
    @lines = IO.readlines(filename)
    @fiber = Fiber.new do
      @lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
        @scanner = StringScanner.new(line)
        @scanner.skip(/\s+/)
        value, kind = nil, nil
        begin 
          got_token = false
          TOKEN_DEF.each do |tok, regex|
            if @scanner.scan(regex)
              Fiber.yield Token.new(tok, value, index, @scanner.pos)
              got_token = true
            end
          end
          raise Retry if got_token
        rescue Retry
          retry
        end
      end
      "fiber is finished"
    end
  end

  def next
    @fiber.resume
  end
end

text_scanner = TextScanner('sometextfile')
puts text_scanner.next #=> first token
puts text_scanner.next #=> second token
puts text_scanner.next #=> third token
...
puts text_scanner.next #=> "fiber is finished"
```

Comment: Thx. That effectively gives me ideas. However, strictly speaking, the solution given does not work : when fiber is resumed, another new line is read, while there still can be tokens to consume in the previous line.

Comment: Still not. The reason is that the redo will not start from the begin of TOKEN_DEF, so if you have several identical token on the same line, it fails.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I deleted my anwser, I'm working on it, so just wait.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a simple solution. Here it is :

```
def next
 @line+=1 while @scanner.skip(/\n/)
 @line+=1 if @scanner.bol?
 @scanner.skip(/\s+/)
 @line+=1 if @scanner.bol?
 @scanner.skip(/\s+/)
 return :eof if @scanner.eos?
 TOKEN_DEF.each { |tok,syntax| (kind=tok;break) if @scanner.scan(syntax)}
 return Token.new(kind,nil,@line,@scanner.pos)
end
```